# Is there a way use a wildcard operator(*) in the File.ReadAllLines method?

Tags: c#, xml, csv, file-conversion

I am trying to do a multiple convert of multiple CSV file to XML, based on this tutorial from Microsoft:

```
// Create the text file.  
string csvString = @"GREAL,Great Lakes Food Market,Howard Snyder,Marketing Manager,(503) 555-7555,2732 Baker Blvd.,Eugene,OR,97403,USA  
HUNGC,Hungry Coyote Import Store,Yoshi Latimer,Sales Representative,(503) 555-6874,City Center Plaza 516 Main St.,Elgin,OR,97827,USA  
LAZYK,Lazy K Kountry Store,John Steel,Marketing Manager,(509) 555-7969,12 Orchestra Terrace,Walla Walla,WA,99362,USA  
LETSS,Let's Stop N Shop,Jaime Yorres,Owner,(415) 555-5938,87 Polk St. Suite 5,San Francisco,CA,94117,USA";  
File.WriteAllText("cust.csv", csvString);  

// Read into an array of strings.  
string[] source = File.ReadAllLines("cust.csv");  
XElement cust = new XElement("Root",  
    from str in source  
    let fields = str.Split(',')  
    select new XElement("Customer",  
        new XAttribute("CustomerID", fields[0]),  
        new XElement("CompanyName", fields[1]),  
        new XElement("ContactName", fields[2]),  
        new XElement("ContactTitle", fields[3]),  
        new XElement("Phone", fields[4]),  
        new XElement("FullAddress",  
            new XElement("Address", fields[5]),  
            new XElement("City", fields[6]),  
            new XElement("Region", fields[7]),  
            new XElement("PostalCode", fields[8]),  
            new XElement("Country", fields[9])  
        )  
    )  
);  
Console.WriteLine(cust);
```

I was planning to use a foreach loop to loop through all the CSV files in the directory that needed to be converted, though I have come to a snag.

In the line:

```
string[] source = File.ReadAllLines("cust.csv");
```

Would there be a way to replace cust.csv with like a wildcard operator(*.csv) so that it takes all the CSV files it runs such as:

```
string[] source = File.ReadAllLines("*.csv");
```

I know the above does not work since ReadAllLines does not support the "*", but what would be the logic for this so that it loops through all CSV files, then applies the logic conversion to them?

Comment: _"but what would be the logic for this so that it loops through all CSV files, then applies the logic conversion to them?"_ -> Get all file names in a given directory that end with ".csv" and then loop through them.

Comment: `str.Split(',')` is not a csv parser. A "proper" csv file may contain quoted values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but what would be the logic for this so that it loops through all CSV files, then applies the logic conversion to them?

You'd first use [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netcore-3.1) or [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netcore-3.1) to list the relevant files in the directory. Both of those *do* support wildcards.

Once you have the files you want to operate on, you can read each of those in turn.